# AWS Lambda - single vs multile productId

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a use case where the client app will make a REST call with MULTIPLE product identifiers and get their details. I have a lambda function(exposed by API gateway) which can take a SINGLE product id and get it's detail. I need to get them to work together.. What is a good solution for this?

1. Modify the client app so it makes single product Id requests. No change in Lambda function required then. But this increases client app network calls as it will invoke the lambda for each productId separately..
2. Modify the lambda function so that it can handle multiple product id's in the same call.. But this increases lambda response time..
3. I was also thinking about creating a new lambda function which takes in the multiple productId's and then calls the single product lambda function.. But not sure how to aggregate the responses before sending back to client app.

Looking for suggestions..

Comment: It seems like each of your 3 options have some trade-offs and you just need to pick which option is most acceptable to you. I don't think anyone is going to be able to answer your question definitively. If you have an actual implementation issue once you chose which option to go with then I would ask that as another question here.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is less optimal as it will move the chatty protocol between the client to server.

If there are no users of a single Id then I would not keep that one alive. (not option #3)

Depending on your language of choice - it might be best to implement 2 (or 3 for this matter). node.js (and C# too btw) makes it very easy to perform multiple calls in parallel (async calls) and then wait for all results and return to the client. 
This means that you will not wait X time more - just a bit more, aligned with your slowest call.
ES6 (modern JS, supported by Lambda) now supports Promise.all() for this purpose.
C# also natively supports these patterns with Task.WaitAll()

Comment: This makes sense.. Do we have the same feature supported by Java - something on the same lines as Promise.all() or Task.WaitAll()  ?

Comment: I have not touched Java for many years now. In the past we achieved similar pattern with multiple threads and then Thread.Join() them. Maybe modern Java has some other means to do so , possibly something like : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html